# Entity return results only after 2 attempts

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have some queries writen on Entity that return results only after 2 attempts, after the thirdy attempt, the results comes normally. I already enabled/disabled lazy loading and nothing... Any ideias?
as
Here is one of the queries that has this issue

_projectId is in class constructor

```
public List<IL_ORG_RGN> getAllRegional()
{
    using (DbEntities model = new DbEntities())
    {
        try
        {
            var data = (from a in model.IL_ORG_RGN where a.ACTIVE == true && a.PROJECT_ID == _projectId select a).ToList();
            return data.ToList()
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Failed to retrieve Regional list " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you get on the attempts that fail?  If it's an exception, please post the text.

Comment: I just get an empty list

Comment: Side Note: Your doubling up on the `ToList()` calls

Comment: The problem isn't in the code you have posted.  Other than calling `ToList` more than you need to, I see no problems with the code that would cause odd behavior.  The problem must be somewhere else in the system or in the data.

Comment: I didn't notice the duplicated  `ToLIst()`... Thaks, guys! Other queries with differente tables are presenting the same behavior. Its really weird, it have been a lot of months with this problem and i cant figure out why